# Async calls with aioboto3/aiobotocore hang when using ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: concurrency, python-asyncio, aiobotocore

I have the case where there are several models, some of which make s3 read/write calls.  I want to execute a predict() function in parallel but some of those predicts have async calls in them, including the calls to s3. So my code looks something like this:

```
class ModelA(BaseModel):

     def predict(self, df):
         # some prediction logic


class ModelB(BaseModel):
     def predict(self, df):
         preds = []
         with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
             for company, comp_df in df.groupby('company_id'):
                 path = f'{some_path}/{company}.pqt'
                 exists = await key_exists(WRITE_BUCKET, path)
                 if exists:
                     # pre-generated OCR output that model relies on
                     preds_df = await self.read_from_s3(path, session)
                 else:
                     preds_df = run_ocr(comp_df)
                 # some prediction logic

async def key_exists(bucket, key):
    async with aioboto3.Session().client("s3") as s3_client:
        try:
            LOGGER.info("entering get object in key_exists")
            await s3_client.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
            LOGGER.info("exiting get object in key_exists")
        except Exception:
            return False
        return True
             
async def run_model(model):
    """
    Wrapper function to run the model.
    """
    # runs underlying predict()
    await model.run_predictions()


async def task_gatherer(subtasks: list):
    """Wrapper for gather function."""
    return await asyncio.gather(*subtasks)


def get_model_tasks(model):
    subtasks = [run_model(model)]
    result = asyncio.run(task_gatherer(subtasks))
    return result


async def run_async_models(async_models):
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(mp_context=mp.get_context('fork')) as pool:
        event_loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        master_tasks = [
            event_loop.run_in_executor(
                pool,
                get_model_tasks,
                model,
            )
            for model in async_models
        ]
        await asyncio.gather(*master_tasks)
```

Now if I run as a standalone script, it runs fine.

```
def main():
    individual_models = [ModelA(), ModelB()]
    for model in individual_models:
        asyncio.run(model.populate_table())
```

Output:

> 2024-02-01 05:24:25,571 - INFO - async_utils - entering get object in key_exists

> 2024-02-01 05:24:25,638 - INFO - async_utils - exiting get object in key_exists

But if I run in processpoolExecutor, it hangs indefinitely, specifically at the key_exists function, which does a call to s3.head_object():

```
async_models = [
    # add new models here:
    ModelA(),
    ModelB()
    ]
    # Run these models in parallel
    asyncio.run(run_async_models(async_models))
```

I've tried sharing the session between the key_exists() function and read_from_s3() function but it doesn't make a difference. I've also tried spawning the processing instead of forking, but that doesn't matter either.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to use ThreadPoolExecutor, not ProcessPoolExecutor. After making the switch it runs to completion.